# How to save Datatables ajax result in a variable

Tags: ajax, datatables

Well, I've been looking for a way to render my tables and modals ("show more") using Datatables, I got the way to convert my data and render html inside `<td>`, but there is a way to save the current result data of JSON response in a variable so I can use it externaly to populate the modal ? Or at least the current content of table. I'm current using version 1.10.4